# How to convert List<scala.Tuple2> to java.util.HashMap?

Tags: apache-spark, java-8

I am using Spark.
In spark after doing a collect on RDDs of `scala.Tuple2<K,V>` I get List of `scala.Tuple2<K,V>`. I want to convert it to a `HashMap<K,V>` in Java.

I can iterate over the list and add it to my HashMap but I am looking for an elegant way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: You want something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/33345553/4969370

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most elegant way in **java** is to use `stream` and `Collectors`.

You can achieve this way:

```
    List<Tuple2<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Tuple2<>("first", "second"));
    list.add(new Tuple2<>("third", "four"));
    list.add(new Tuple2<>("five", "six"));
    list.add(new Tuple2<>("seven", "eight"));
    list.add(new Tuple2<>("nine", "ten"));

    System.out.println("List of Tuple2s:" + list); 

    //convert list of tupples to Map with one line
    Map<String, String> resultMap = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Tuple2::_1, Tuple2::_2));

    System.out.println("Map of Tuples2s: "+resultMap);
```

**Output:**

```
    List of Tuple2s:[(first,second), (third,four), (five,six), (seven,eight), (nine,ten)]
    Map of Tuples2s: {nine=ten, third=four, seven=eight, five=six, first=second}
```

But what about duplicate keys?? When we add another item to list like: `list.add(new Tuple2<>("first", "ten"));` exception occures:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate
>   key second    at
>   java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$throwingMerger$0(Collectors.java:133)
>     at java.util.HashMap.merge(HashMap.java:1253)

If you are not sure whether you can have duplicates you can do:

```
    Map<String, String> resultMap = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Tuple2::_1, Tuple2::_2,
                    (x, y) -> {
                        System.out.println("duplicate key!");
                        return x;
                    }));
```

and avoid overwriting item in `Map`.

**Output:**

```
List of Tuple2s:[(first,second), (third,four), (five,six), (seven,eight), (nine,ten), (first,ten)]
duplicate key!
Map of Tuples2s: {nine=ten, third=four, seven=eight, five=six, first=second}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Scala you can do:

```
scala> import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

scala> val tuples = List((1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5))
scala> tuples.toMap.asJava
res1: java.util.Map[Int,Int] = {1=2, 2=3, 4=5}
```

Comment: I mentioned java in the question.