# Can a stream collect opreation can be a specific POJO instead of a Map?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I would like to groupBy multiple fields and produce and the output that is a POJO.

The Original POJO is something like this:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class DealDTO {
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String id;

    private Float amount;
    private Date closeDate;
    private String stage;

    public int getYear() {
        return getLocalDate().getYear();
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return getLocalDate().getMonthValue();
    }

    private LocalDate getLocalDate() {
        return getCloseDate().toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    }
}
```

The Target POJO

```
@Data
public class GroupByYearMonthStageDTO {
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private String stage;
    private DoubleSummaryStatistics statistics;
}
```

The code bellow produce the expected grouping:

```
List<DealDTO> list;
var grouping = list.stream().collect(
  groupingBy(DealDTO::getYear,
    groupingBy(DealDTO::getMonth,
      groupingBy(DealDTO::getStage, summarizingDouble(DealDTO::getAmount)))));
```

But.....the grouping is of type :

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<String, DoubleSummaryStatistics>>>
```

I would like to see if there is a way in the collect operation to change the output to have a final grouping type of:

```
List<GroupByYearMonthStageDTO>
```

Comment: what is `DealDTO`? and on a list of `OriginalPojo` you're performing operations to attributes of `TargetPojo` in your code, which makes less sense. Please clarify the question further.

Comment: DealDTO is the Original POJO.  It contain all methods refereed in the groupingBy operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As first parameter for `groupingBy` send the lambda which creates your target POJO and as second parameter use `summarizingDouble` collector. After this you'll have to traverse the resulted map and set the statistics

```
Map<GroupByYearMonthStageDTO, DoubleSummaryStatistics> collect = list.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(d -> new GroupByYearMonthStageDTO(d.getYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getStage()),
                            summarizingDouble(DealDTO::getAmount)));

collect.forEach(GroupByYearMonthStageDTO::setStatistics);
Set<GroupByYearMonthStageDTO> groupByYearMonthStageDTOS = collect.keySet();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `Target POJO` looks like I can't really implement this *for* you, but what you will need is a custom `Collector` implementation. Once you've done your grouping, you can pass the grouped data to your `Collector`, and it must reduce it from the grouped data into your POJO.

Note that it may even be desirable to skip grouping and instead let your `Collector` handle it.

Helpful links:

[Java Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html)

[groupingBy()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)

[Java 8 grouping using custom collector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345413/java-8-grouping-using-custom-collector)

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I include the POJOs in the original post to make it more clear.  Implementing a custom Collector, this is where I'm getting stuck.  All the example found is showing with only one level of grouping.